# While JMeter Execution in NON-GUI Mode got as **EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffb9ff30963, pid=6832, tid=29208**

Tags: performance, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

While executing the Load Test in NON-GUI Mode and CPU Utilization is hitting 100% and RAM capacity is 8GB. Memory Utilization while executing the test in NON-GUI Mode is 80-86%(7-7.2GB) is being utilizing by OS and  executed the test with 50 V users and in the first 5minutes 25 users are in active state and 25 users are in finished state.

Also got errors as below:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sufhq.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deFET.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can run 50 Chrome browser instances on a machine with 8 GB of RAM.

I fail to find Chrome browser system requirements anywhere but [Firefox 114](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/114.0/system-requirements/) needs 1 CPU core and 2 GB of RAM per instance and my expectation is that Chrome needs at least that many or even more.

So given JMeter 5.5 [default heap size of 1 GB](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/bin/jmeter.bat#L151), your operating system takes a couple of gigabytes you can run 1-2 browser instances maximum without running out of resources.

Moreover using Selenium for performance testing is [not recommended either by Selenium developers](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/test_practices/discouraged/performance_testing/)

> Performance testing using Selenium and WebDriver is generally not advised. Not because it is incapable, but because it is not optimised for the job and you are unlikely to get good results.

or by [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/) developers:

> Note: It is NOT the intention of this project to replace the HTTP Samplers included in JMeter. Rather it is meant to compliment them by measuring the end user load time.

Assuming all above the options are in:

1. Either switch to [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers, given you [configure JMeter to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) it shouldn't be any difference whether you're using Selenium or HTTP Request samplers from the system under test perspective
2. Or if you still want to run your test using real browsers despite what I'm and other people saying you will need to get more machines and run your test in [distributed mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)